# How do I allow users to upload photos and comments to my facebook app?

Tags: facebook, comments, photos

I need to allow my app's users to upload a photo to the app (not to change their Facebook profile photo) so that other app users (who are not necessarily Facebook friends of the uploader), can see the photo **only** via this app and comment on it.

What is the right way to do this?

One idea I have in mind is opening a Facebook page for my app and when a user uploads a photo it will be uploaded to app's page. Then when other app users want to see photos and comments they will be loaded from this FB page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow users to upload photos within your app, store those photos on your server and post them to your pages wall on behalf of your page.  You can read from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) under the title "Page Login" and learn how to retrieve the correct access token and make calls as a page.
Once you have the photos posted as the page, they will be in the list of your pages photos and  you'll be albe to store their pid/aid and use those ids to retrieve, add comments/likes on the photos.

Comment: After posting the photo on the wall of my page, can I delete the photo that is stored on my server? does it make any difference if I post it in page's "Photos" instead of the wall? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to make sure that you keep a copy of that photo then yes, you should store a copy on your own server.  Having said that photos being stored on facebook are about as safe as any other piece of information facebook keeps.  With regard to the wall/photos, if you post to a wall it will get put in the wall photo's album, however you can post the photo directly into an album you want simply by posting to `https://graph.facebook.com/{album_id}` with the correct access token.

Comment: Does my app need to ask the manage_pages token only once?  then each app user will be able to post photos using the same access token?